# Not able to trim timestamp format in sql loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, time-format

I am new to SQL loader and unable to trim the timestamp format while loading data via SQL loader.
my control file looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE MyTable
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(
column1,
column2,
column3,
column4,
DATE EXPRESSION "current_timestamp(1)"
)
```

The date column loaded in MyTable is in below format:
18-FEB-20 18.10.33.700000000

I want to trim the milliseconds from the output(.700000000). My output should be "18-FEB-20 18.10.33". Is there a way to do it via SQL loader itself?

Comment: Try using `"current_date"` instead of `"current_timestamp(1)"`. If that doesn't work, you might be able to use the Oracle `FORMAT` function to format the timestamp string.

Comment: @digital.aaron "current_date" is only displaying the date and not time.

Comment: You need "DATE EXPRESSION current_timestamp(0)". In format timestamp(n), n tell Oracle the number digits to keep for fractional seconds.

Comment: Are you trying to say that column5 in your table is a date datatype and you are trying to load timestamp data into it?

Comment: @Gary_W. The name of column 5 is date. The datatype is timestamp only. This is working fine but I don't want fractional seconds in my output

Comment: @Belayer. If i keep current_timestamp(0), it prints the millisecond values as all zeros. Something like this 18-FEB-20 18.10.33.000000000

Answer (score 0):

`TO_CHAR(current_timestamp(1), 'DD-MON-YY hh:mi:ss')` works in a SELECT statement to format `current_timestamp(1)` like you are requesting. I'm not sure if the same syntax will work in SQL-Loader, but I'd expect something very similar to work for what you need.

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(current_timestamp(1), 'DD-MON-YY hh:mi:ss')
FROM DUAL
```